# Laravel get single item from Array in Query with relation ship

Tags: php, laravel

in my one of models such as `posts` i have a column array as `featured_image` and when i get result query from this model that return all of this array items, for example:

```
"featured_image": {
    "images": {
        "original": "/uploads/post_images/2020/1598873165.jpg",
        "300": "/uploads/post_images/2020/300_1598873165.jpg",
        "900": "/uploads/post_images/2020/900_1598873165.jpg"
    },
    "thumbnail": "/uploads/post_images/2020/300_1598873165.jpg"
},
```

now how can i modify this below query to get only one item from this array such as `thumbnail`?

```
public function allData()
{
    $posts = Post::with(['groups', 'categories' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereLocked(false);
    }])->wherePublished(true)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts,
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: `featured_images` is a relation or what?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte `featured_image` is a column on `Posts` model

Comment: You have a JSON stored in this column?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes, thats right, like with pasted output in post

Comment: You'll probably have to use a `join()` (or similar) to extract `featured_image->thumbnail` to a column, then pass forward in your response. You could iterate `$posts` and do `$post->thumbnail = $post->feature_image->thumbnail;`, but that's potentially quite slow.

Comment: You can do what you want with PHP but the proper solution would involve a change in your database tables. Another solution would be to use mutators (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to cast the json to array, but still you need to retrieve all data and manually extract only the `thumbnail`.

Comment: What database you have? You can also try to use some built-in function in `select` clause to extract the key you want.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte my database is `MySql`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
public function allData()
{
    $posts = Post::with(['groups', 'categories' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereLocked(false);
    }])->wherePublished(true)
    ->select('{primary must included to use With}', 'other', 'columns', 'featured_image->thumbnail as thumbnail')
    ->get();
    return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts,
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: One quick fix, `featured_image->thumbnails` would be `featured_image->thumbnail` (no 's', not pluralized)

Comment: No problem! And you tag like this: @TimLewis (@ before my username, with no spaces), but I got notified anyway (if only 1 person has commented, they are notified)

Comment: @AlzafanChristian how about relationships? such as `'groups', 'categories'`, i don't have them in output of query